# How I can Run Multiple Node js Files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I am new to node.js I have question about how to run mulitple files at once.
let's say I have `scripts_1.js` and `scripts_2.js`
How can I run the both at the same time.
I know I can do this `node scripts_1.js && scripts_2.js` but the problem is that I need to wait for `scripts_1` to finish so `scripts_2.js` can run.

I tried bash scripts
`start.sh`

```
start node "scripts_1.js"
start node "scripts_2.js"
```

but I don't like it I need a better way.
any one can help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What about `node scripts_1.js && node scripts_2.js`? That _should_ wait for the first `node` execution to finish before the second.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want that I want the both to run at the same time

Comment: Oh, then just use one ampersand: `node scripts_1.js & node scripts_2.js`

Comment: is this work too with python, like `python scripts_1.py & python scriopts_2.py` ?

Comment: yeah, it's shell scripting so it doesn't matter what you're calling from shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run multiple commands *asynchronously* by separating them with **one** ampersand in shell:

```sh
node scripts_1.js & node scripts_2.js
```